# Keep certain number of lines

Tags: php

I want to keep just an exact number of line from this, it takes a file reverse it and echo it, but the file might get to long and want to limit it to a number of lines.

```
$file = file("update.log");
$file = array_reverse($file);

foreach($file as $f){
 if (stripos($f, "Sale") !== false) {
    $class = "sales";
 } else{
    $class = "row";
 }

 echo "<div class='".$class." scale'>".$f."</div>";
}
```

Comment: If you want limit then use `for loop` or `while loop`

Comment: How do you want to combine limitation and reversing? Do you want to take the first 100 lines and reverse them, or do you want to take the _last_ 100 lines and reverse them, precisely because the result should be reversed? - However, in `PHP` you may simply exit a loop with `break`.

Comment: That's last number of lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a counter and when it hits the max_lines number break out of the foreach loop.

```
$file = file("update.log");
$file = array_reverse($file);

$count = 0;
$max_lines = 100;    
foreach($file as $f){
 if ($count >= $max_lines){
  break;
 }
 if (stripos($f, "Sale") !== false) {
    $class = "sales";
 } else{
    $class = "row";
 }
 $count++;

 echo "<div class='".$class." scale'>".$f."</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = file("update.log");
$file = array_reverse($file);
$lineLimit = 25;
$lineCounter = 0;

foreach($file as $f){
 if (stripos($f, "Sale") !== false) {
    $class = "sales";
 } else{
    $class = "row";
 }
 echo "<div class='".$class." scale'>".$f."</div>";
 $lineCounter++;
 if($lineCounter > $lineLimit)
    break; //Will exit the loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is faster and more flexible in avoiding memory problems. You don't have to read every line of the file so you could use something like this:

```
function viewLastLines($logfile,$maxlines=25) {
    $handle = fopen($logfile, "r");
    fseek($handle, -($maxlines),SEEK_END);
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false)
        $outputlines[]=$line;
    fclose($handle);
    return $outputlines;
}
```

Use it like this in your case:

```
$file = array_reverse(viewLastLines("update.log",100));
foreach($file as $f){
    if (stripos($f, "Sale") !== false) $class = "sales";
    else $class = "row";
    echo "<div class='".$class." scale'>".$f."</div>";
}
```